# How can the appearance of different faiths be made possible even with direct access to a creator deity?

Tags: society, religion, gods

When the creator created humanity, he created two humans who were meant to be perfect and the first of their species. However, they betrayed his trust when they got too hungry and ate a fruit that was forbidden to them. After he cast them out of his garden, they had two sons who both competed for their parents' affections.

This also ended badly when one ended up killing the other, and was marked for life as the first murderer. The experiment called humanity was beginning to look like an abysmal failure. However, the creator came up with a solution that would hopefully turn this into a worthwhile investment. Instead of simply leaving humanity to their own devices, he assigned a group of angels to be the caretakers of humanity and tasked them with guiding the young race in the right path. These beings were known as the watchers.

The civil war in heaven which ended with the casting out of Lucifer Morningstar(https://lucifer.fandom.com/wiki/Lucifer_Morningstar)
and his allies had left the celestial realm in chaos and disorder. The creator was wary of who to assign his task of watching over humanity to, and limited his selection to only the most loyal beings under his command. Even after carefully making his selections, he still had the nagging suspicion that these watchers would fornicate with humanity, leading to a race of giants that would attempt to conquer it, which would force him to flood the planet and start from scratch. Fortunately, that did not happen and the watchers actually did their job.

Although they couldn't interfere with humanity directly, they were the direct link between the humans and their god. They would transmit his guidance and teachings word for word, so that there would be no confusion as to what his principles were. Because of this direct access, there could be no misinterpretation about teachings or legitimacy about what is canonical and true. Given these circumstances, there would be no need for the appearance of different religions or sects within faiths that would cause schisms or reformations.

How would it be possible for these goals to fail under these improved conditions to our timeline?

Comment: (1) You missed the opportunity to link to [Lucifer Morningstar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_(TV_series)). (2) Profet Mohammed, peace be upon him, was *"the direct link between the humans and God, who would transmit His guidance and teachings word for word, so that there would be no confusion as to what His principles were"*. How come we are not all Muslims already? (In other words, just because a group of fraudsters calling themselves watchers pretend to have direct access to God Almighty does not mean that all humans believe them like obedient sheep.)

Comment: There are many ways this could fail. After all, humans be human. VTC:OB.

Answer (score 3):

Think of it in terms of real life fandoms, who have direct access to the creator and can directly ask questions. Are they united, with one true faith? No, they have scisms, fierce debates, and endless arguments.

There are several things that cause this.

1. Subjects not mentioned. Does god give extensive advice on obscure sexual fetishes? What do they say about very odd specific situations? There may well be many subjects they didn't get around to addressing where there are diverse views.
2. Interpretations of ambiguous statements. Humans are very good at reading stuff into statements. They can argue if one statement means or implies something, or if another one modifies a sentence.
3. Who counts as canon and who does not? They will surely record the statements of every angel. What if one makes a remark that is taken as the word of god? What if one expresses their view on an issue and it's not totally accurate?
4. Divided base. If people really don't like a particular view, or have a chosen canon pairing they may decide to ignore evidence against their case and push a particular interpretation.
5. Later statements vs earlier statements. Is god's view and mood consistent? How do you interpret two contradictory statements, or ones that seem to contradict? Can you mix and match them for extra confusion?
6. Lucifer Morningstar can push their own message and confusion. They can masquerade as angels and push views, or push one perspective or another. They could form a rival religious group, or try to form a synthesis group integrating their teachings with god's.

Constant advice won't fix this issue. Only the most learned of scholars will be able to remember every word, and even they will be able to martial many statements for and against a view. Increased complexity just makes things harder.

Answer (score 1):

The guidance stopped at a certain point.

After that, divergence of opinions started, first between around the proper order of mixing milk and tea, then around the proper placing of the toilet paper, then around topping pizzas with pineapples followed by the right side from which one should start peeling a banana.

I mean, look at kids: despite being grown and educated by the same parents, each develops its own quirks and character. Same goes with guidance, no matter how heavenly it is. As soon as they are left free to choose, they take divergent paths.

Answer (score 1):

@NepeneNep posted a great answer. I upvoted it and I encourage you to do so. My answer is perhaps a refinement or expansion of what Nepene stated.

**Assumption:** Your average person does NOT have direct access to the Creator. They have, at best, direct access to a Giant. The Giant has direct access to the Creator.

**1. There are so many people, so few giants**

I'm not convinced that direct access to a Creator guarantees unified belief. After all <s>Adam and Eve</s> your two hungry humans, the only two humans on the planet at the time, *disobeyed.* There was schism quite literally from <s>day six</s> day one. This problem only gets worse as the number of people and the distance between those people and the Creator increases.

A time comes when *intermediaries* arrive — giants. There are fewer giants than humans, so humans only rarely have regular access to those who actually have direct access. The greater the length of time between visits, the more likely differences in interpretation and/or experience increase.

**2. Is there one true faith?**

Today IRL we have the situation where some religious organizations believe they are the one, true faith; that all other religious traditions are false and inadequate to bring one to the fullness of God's blessings. There are others who believe that there is not one true faith, but that the differences of operations merely reflect the differences of people, but that one loving God embraces all so long as the basics are observed (and even that's up for debate, at least from humanity's POV, is baptism a required ordinance or not?).

- If your world has but one true faith, then what you have are heretics that grow from individuals or groups who personally want something that's blocked by the faith — greed, lust, power, etc. These groups cause divergence when there isn't anyone nearby to correct them to achieve their own personal goals. So, in this condition, there is one true faith but many heresies that the Giants (frankly, like the Apostle Paul) are constantly visiting over and over to correct those heresies.
- If your world allows many minor interpretations or differences such that many faiths can fulfill the purposes of the Creator, then you have a lot of churches and the Giants are more like shepherds of different flocks of sheep. The sheep vary in color, count, even the type or quality of wool, and location, but they're all sheep and are all good for (if you'll forgive the metaphor) mutton and sweaters.

Which or both of those paths have more to do with *why* your Creator is doing what he/she/it is doing. One would think that a god, above all others, would have a reason for acting as they do.

**3. Of robots and men**

There are many IRL that believe the purpose of humanity is to give their wills wholly over to God. Some see this is subverting free will (as if free will were a curse and not a give), turning people into robots or slaves of the Creator. There are others IRL that revere free will above pretty much all else. The two perspectives have their pros and cons. The first leads to greater obedience but less (if it can be said this way) value of the human person, there is less ability to color outside the lines and a greater propensity to become vapor-locked when faced with new situations. The latter has greater disobedience (a greater ability to stay outside the lines), but the human person who chooses to obey is more valuable, capable of facing new situations and overcome them without direct intervention.

So, what kind of Creator do you have? One that expects perfect robots or capable people? If the later, you'll have greater interpretation of the "rules" as the followers of free will try to work out how "this problem" fits into the limited instructions they've received.